# Sync MySQL DB using Master Slave Approach - Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, synchronization, multiple-databases

I am using a certain API to fetch data from a server and store it my DB. Since the size of the data is very large, I am doing it this way as real-time fetching would take a lot of time.The point is the master DB might be updated: records updated, created or even dropped from the DB.
To update the DB, one way is to re-fetch the data again and check each record if any changes have occured to it. This way is not efficient.

Is there any other way to do DB synchronization between both of them ensuring that my DB is up to date?!